# query on distances using euclidean distance measure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently trying to create a query that will calculate the distances between two points with given lat/long values. I have constructed a query so far but am running into several errors and not sure I am on the right path! Any guidance or advice would be appreciated. I am new to oracle.

Code so far:

```
DECLARE
  lat NUMBER := -12;
  lon NUMBER := 130;
BEGIN
SELECT x_id
FROM x
WHERE x_id = sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + (lon - longitude, 2))
END;  
/
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: where are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are using simple SQL statement in you anonymous block. You need to use a variable to receive the value returned by the query.
Power function is missing for the calculation for longitude.
Also semicolon ';' is missing at the end of the query.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  lat NUMBER := -12;
  lon NUMBER := 130;
  lv_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT x_id INTO lv_id
FROM x
WHERE x_id = sqrt(power(lat - latitude, 2) + power(lon - longitude, 2));
dbms_output.put_line('ID : '||lv_id);
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('ID Not Found');
WHEN too_many_rows THEN
   dbms_output.put_line('More than one ID Not Found');
END;  
/
```